# Problems exporting a list of images with .fileExporter()

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiimage

I'm trying to generate some images from SwiftUI views, and then export them to the filesystem. I've looked online and can't seem to get things to work. Tapping the file export button does nothing.

Should I be converting the images to a different format? I feel like I'm missing something obvious, this is harder than it should be.

```
struct Temp: View {
    let screenshots: [ScreenshotModel]
    let size: CGSize

    @State private var isShowingExport = false

    @State private var exportImages = [UIImage]()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(exportImages, id: \.self) {
                    Image(uiImage: $0)
                }

                Button("Export to Files", systemImage: "folder") {
                    isShowingExport.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            await generateImages()
        }
        .fileExporter(
            isPresented: $isShowingExport,
            items: exportImages.map { $0.pngData()! }
        ) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success:
                print("Success")
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        } onCancellation: { }
    }

    func generateImages() async {
        exportImages = await withTaskGroup(of: UIImage.self) { group in
            for screenshot in screenshots {
                group.addTask {
                    await generateImage(screenshot: screenshot)
                }
            }

            var allImages = [UIImage]()
            for await image in group {
                allImages.append(image)
            }

            return allImages
        }
    }

    @MainActor
    func generateImage(screenshot: ScreenshotModel) -> UIImage {
        let content = ScreenshotPreviewView(
            screenshotModel: screenshot,
            size: size
        ).frame(size: size)

        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: content)

        return renderer.uiImage!
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `func generateImages(...)`, you should have
     `exportImages = allImages` instead of `return allImages`

Comment: That's not true, I'm using `withTaskGroup` which provides a closure, and the return value of the closure is returned by `withTaskGroup`.

Comment: yes, sorry my bad, you are correct. I tested your code with simulated images and all works well for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this approach using `.fileExporter(isPresented: ..., documents: ...)` and `ImageDocument: FileDocument` as shown.

Example code:

Note in particular the `fw.filename` to give each file a different name.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // for testing
        Temp(screenshots: [ScreenshotModel(name: "house"),ScreenshotModel(name: "globe")], size: .zero)
    }
}

// for testing
struct ScreenshotModel: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

struct Temp: View {
    let screenshots: [ScreenshotModel]
    let size: CGSize

    @State private var isShowingExport = false

    @State private var exportImages = [UIImage]()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(exportImages, id: \.self) {
                    Image(uiImage: $0)
                }

                Button("Export to Files", systemImage: "folder") {
                    isShowingExport.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            await generateImages()
        }
        .fileExporter(
            isPresented: $isShowingExport,
            documents: exportImages.map{ImageDocument(image: $0)} // <-- here
        ) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success:
                print("-----> Success")
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        } onCancellation: { }
    }

    func generateImages() async {
        exportImages = await withTaskGroup(of: UIImage.self) { group in
            for screenshot in screenshots {
                group.addTask {
                    await generateImage(screenshot: screenshot)
                }
            }

            var allImages = [UIImage]()
            for await image in group {
                allImages.append(image)
            }

            return allImages
        }
    }

    @MainActor
    func generateImage(screenshot: ScreenshotModel) async -> UIImage { // <-- here
//        let content = ScreenshotPreviewView(
//            screenshotModel: screenshot,
//            size: size
//        ).frame(size: size)
//
//        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: content)
//
//        return renderer.uiImage!
        
        // for testing
        return UIImage(systemName: screenshot.name)!
    }
}

struct ImageDocument: FileDocument {
  static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [.png] }

  var image: UIImage

  init(image: UIImage?) {
    self.image = image ?? UIImage()
  }

  init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
    guard let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents,
          let image = UIImage(data: data)
    else {
      throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
    }
    self.image = image
  }

  func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
      let fw = FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: image.pngData()!)
      fw.filename = String(UUID().uuidString.prefix(6))  // <--- for testing
      return fw
  }
}
```

Comment: Haven't tested it yet, but I specifically used the ImageRenderer because there's an async aspect to this. My gut is telling me this will trigger the file exporter with an empty list of images, but I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Looks like it worked! Must be a bug that the Transferable type Image doesn't work with the `items:` API.